# How to write regex for a string contains with pipe symbol in java?

Tags: java, regex

i want to check a value should be like **"abcss|defs|cedff"**

How to write a regex for matching this in java?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We can apply this split("\\|");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\w+\|\w+\|\w+` for example :

```
"abcss|defs|cedff".matches("\\w+\\|\\w+\\|\\w+")
```

---

**Note**
You have to use backslash `\|` to escape the `|` not just the `|`